# Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know this is the same quetion title like others, but i cant find the right answer for me. Here is my problem.

I am trying to insert data to the other table after users data inserted. But what i got is `Call to a member function create() on null`.

Here is my code of AuthController.php

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);


    $user->usersbasics()->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

Here is my User model

```
public function usersbasics()
{
    $this->hasOne('App\UsersBasics');
}
```

Here is my UsersBasics model:

```
public function user()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I tried `var_dumb($user->usersbasics())` and the result is NULL.
What is whrong with my code? because i use the same for my other work, and its fine. Please someone explain me and give me a solution. Please..

thank you,

Comment: Are you including/using the `User` model ?

Comment: And then change to what? Yes i using the User in my AuthController

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer, but I ran into the same problem.

You don't have the return keyword on both your relationships.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

and

```
public function usersbasics()
{
  return  $this->hasOne('App\UsersBasics');
}
```

This fixxed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for this :) was missing the "return" too

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the parameters `fillable` in your User model.

```
class User extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method is protected instead of public.

If you look at the existing AuthController, we have function you mentioned:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

This method is then called with postRegister (public, so it can be called from routes.php), where we pass only the input from Request as the parameter.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

I assume you tried to call the create() method directly from controller, which doesn't work because it's protected and can only be called from within the class itself. If you really want to make create() method work without postRegister, you would do something like this:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
    ]);


    $user->usersbasics()->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

And then call this in your routes.php

```
Route::post('urlToPostMethod', 'Auth\AuthController@create');
```

The other, generally nicer way would be to call this instead

```
Route::post('urlToPostMethod', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```